# can mis-seated RAM break USB ports?

Tags: usb, memory, motherboard

I've been trying to figure out an issue with my RAM, and as I was (un)plugging the RAM, after one startup I apparently had mis-seated the RAM so the computer failed to post. I'm not sure if it was at that point, or sometime later but as far as I can tell the front panel card readers and USB ports no longer work. The audio jacks are just fine, but nothing else seems to provide power.

Is it possible that the mis-seated RAM caused the problem? I haven't totally dug into it and made sure that everything was connected properly, but it *appears* that things are connected from what I can tell. If that's possible then, boo. Otherwise I'll probably take another look to make sure there's nothing else sketchy. The motherboard is from a Lenovo M78 (pretty sure it's an A75, at least that's the biggest thing printed on the mobo).

Comment: It's possible that while playing with the RAM, you unplugged/damaged the cable from the front panel USB to the motherboard. Or you might have accidentally fried something due to static electricity (you grounded yourself before playing with your PC components, right?). But generally speaking, I'd be hard-pressed to believe that mis-seated RAM could break a USB port...

Comment: Yes, it’s possible

Comment: Front panel doesn't work, okay. What about rear USB ports?

Comment: @AliChen rear ones work - though I'm not sure if they're getting low voltage or something. At least when I plug in my wireless mouse adapter (logitech unifying receiver) it has to be within about 18" of the adapter. And my Bastron 2.4(G?M?)Hz receiver doesn't even work at all. (I used to have them both plugged in to the front panel. They both work fine when plugged into another computer)